# Can Mandarin pronunciation be coded by ARPABET phone set?

Tags: audio, linguistics, phonetics, phoneme

The code doesn't need to be exactly correct. A pronunciation in English can be used to represent a similar pronunciation in Chinese, e.g. /ʈ͡ʂ/ can use "CH" to represent.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

How close do you want to get?

ARPABET was designed for [General American English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American_English).

You can compare the charts for consonants in the above article to a similar chart for [Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology). It looks to me like there are some significant differences.

But I suspect a bigger issue is going to be that tonality is fundamental to vowel production in Mandarin.